# WPF to authenticate against ASP.NET MVC Rest Service using basic authentication

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, rest, authentication, service

I'm working on a WPF application which is consuming an ASP.NET MVC (Restful Behavior). MVC application is using Basic Authentication. So, how can I authenticate my WPF application to access MVC Url? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var username = "john";
    var password = "secret";

    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat(username, ":", password));
    var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;
    var task = client.GetAsync("https://example.com/somemethod");
    if (task.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrong credentials");
    }
    else
    {
        task.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(task.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result);
    }
}
```